# How to shorten a large if-else scenario?

Tags: c#

Is there any suggestion on how to optimize, and shorten this if case:

```
if (secound < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour}:{Minute}:0{secound}";
if (Minute< 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour}:0{Minute}:{secound}";
if (Hour < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"0{Hour}:{Minute}:{secound}";
if(secound <10 && Minute < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour}:0{Minute}:0{secound}";
if (secound < 10 && Hour < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"0{Hour}:{Minute}:0{secound}";
if(Minute < 10 && Hour < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"0{Hour}:0{Minute}:{secound}";
if(Hour < 10 && Minute < 10 && secound < 10)
    TimerLabel.Text = $"0{Hour}:0{Minute}:0{secound}";
```

Comment: Seven if statements is not a loop

Comment: Instead of using 3 different `int`s, you could use only 1 `int` (the seconds) and then convert the seconds to the full HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: See [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just one line. Use [string numeric formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

```
TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour:D2}:{Minute:D2}:{secound:D2}";
```

The letter D (format specifier) followed by a numeric values (precision specifier) instruct the formatting code to supply enough "0" characters to fill the required space

Answer (score 5):

Just use [String.Format syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

```
TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour:00}:{Minute:00}:{Second:00}");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to specify the [numeric format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) of each component:

```
 TimerLabel.Text = $"{Hour:D2}:{Minute:D2}:{secound:D2}";
```

`D2` = decimal output, two characters

Answer (score 0):

Often we don't want to work with `Hour`, `Minute`, `second` *separately* (just imagine how comlex it'll be to perform a very simple operation like adding `5` hours, `59` minutes and `47` seconds), but with `TimeSpan` which has been *specially desinged* for this:

```
   TimeSpan period = new TimeSpan(Hour, Minute, second);

   ...

   TimerLabel.Text = period.ToString();
```

In case `Hour`, `Minute`, `second` means *time*, not a *period* use `DateTime`:

```
   DateTime time = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(Hour, Minute, second));

   ...

   TimerLabel.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Im making a form (Timer form) to display a timer  but timespan does not do the Job for my case (and i didnt know about the timespan interface so thanks !).